# Handling unkown thread in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure which kills the sleeping processes, but the loop keeps running and I am not getting the  result. The loop keeps running.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `uKillSleepingSessions`(v_time INT )
BEGIN

DECLARE no_more_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_ID bigint(4);
DECLARE v_time INT;

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID
FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST PL
WHERE PL.COMMAND='Sleep' AND DB='test'
AND PL.TIME = v_time ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1329
SET no_more_rows = 1;
OPEN my_cur;
SET num_rows = FOUND_ROWS();

IF
num_rows > 0 THEN

FETCH my_cur
INTO V_ID;
END IF;
the_loop: LOOP
IF no_more_rows = 1 THEN  
CLOSE my_cur;
LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;
IF
num_rows > 0 THEN
SET @sql= CONCAT("KILL ",V_ID);
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
END IF;
SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP the_loop;
END
```

Please suggest me where it is wrong. And how can I modify it.
    can the proc be modified to handle unknown thread.
    Thanks

Comment: Are you running with the `PROCESS` privilege turned on?

Comment: `PROCESS` option allows you to see "threads" in other connections and other user logins.  see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process  Also, when you say "unknown" are you claiming these threads have no ID value?

Answer (score 0):

basically cursor fetches all the ID in select statement but sometimes while processing a ID it might not there , so when the sql statement in the prepare statement executes, the lost ID will not be there, so it throws unknown thread. There is no manual to handle this..please suggest if anyone knows it.